# Spliting up name and time into a new row

Tags: r

I have a data set that looks like this:

```
Name <- c("Tom (20)", "35.33L","45.44L", "Mary (18)", "45.00L", "1:25.96")
data.frame(Name)

    Name
1     Tom (20)
2  35.33L
3  45.44L
4    Mary (18)
5  45.00L
6 1:25.96
```

And I want to create a new column call time and put all the time values in. Any idea on how to split them up??

Want it to look like this:

```
  Name    Time
1  Tom (20)  35.33L
2  Tom (20) 45.44L
3 Mary (18)  45.00L
4 Mary (18) 1:25.96
```

Comment: Which of these are time values? What does L signify? What would the desired output look like?

Comment: L mean Long course and there's S in the dataframe as well as short course

Comment: Do individuals always have two times? What's the best logic to use to determine what is a time vs. a name - is position enough or should we test if the string has any numbers?

Comment: they all have different times, some have more than 10 and others might have only 2. it all depends

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Time = replace(Name, grepl('\\(\\d+\\)', Name), NA), 
         Name = replace(Name, !is.na(Time), NA)) %>%
  fill(Name) %>%
  filter(!is.na(Time))

#      Name    Time
#1  Tom (20)  35.33L
#2  Tom (20)  45.44L
#3 Mary (18)  45.00L
#4 Mary (18) 1:25.96
```

Since every person would have an age we separate out the values that follow the pattern `(number)` and divide the data in two columns `Name` and `Time`.

Comment: I have tried this code, however, I don't understand the logic behind it. Also as I actually have other column behind, how do I keep that inside still? Let me select that whole column out and try again

Comment: 1. I added some explanation in the answer. 2. So what happens after you tried the code? Does it work as expected, returns an error, gives incorrect output? 3. I don't understand what you mean by `I actually have other column behind, how do I keep that inside still?`. I don't know how your real data is different from the example shown.

Comment: Alright, after I have tried it. The name value become NS. I think it does work that well is because in my dataset . They have age after the name and it look like this: Tom (20). Any idea?

Comment: We need to come up with a rule which uniquely identifies the name. Does every person has an age? Can I assume that if a value has `()` in them it is a name and rest of it is `Time` ?

Comment: I think that might work, cause upon checking, everyone will have an age

Comment: Thank you so much and it works. May I ask what is this stand for,l('\\(\\d+\\)'

Comment: `(` and `)` are special characters in regex and they hold a special meaning. To match them literally we escape them with double backslash \\.  `\\d+` means one or more number.

Answer (score 0):

We could do this in `dplyr` by creating a grouping column

```
library(dplyr) 
library(stringr)
tibble(Name) %>%
   group_by(grp = cumsum(str_detect(Name, '^[A-Za-z]'))) %>% 
   summarise(Time = Name[-1], Name = Name[1], .groups = 'drop') %>%
   select(Name, Time)
# A tibble: 4 x 2
#  Name      Time   
#  <chr>     <chr>  
#1 Tom (20)  35.33L 
#2 Tom (20)  45.44L 
#3 Mary (18) 45.00L 
#4 Mary (18) 1:25.96
```